# How to free space taken by rdiff-backup data?

Tags: rdiff-backup

I use rdiff-backup for my backups. My disk runs out of space.

I would like to clean some rdiff-backup data by removing either:

- the backup data of small files with a large number of different versions
- the backup data of very large files which have been deleted

In order to free space, how to identify those files?

Comment: The number of versions doesn't matter much, since (if I recall correctly) rdiff-backup uses hardlinks between snapshots. Also, define "not necessary to backup".

Comment: Clarified both points